# Summation query changes values when joined to another table

Tags: mysql

have created the following query which produces a report on total sales. It produces the result that I expected. I am using MySQL and the query looks like:

```
SELECT detailed_report.title AS title,
detailed_report.nid AS nid,
detailed_report.price AS 'price',
SUM(detailed_report.quantity) AS 'total_quantity',
SUM(detailed_report.total) AS 'total_revenue' 
FROM (SELECT uc_order_products.nid AS 'nid',
uc_orders.order_id AS 'order_id',
uc_order_products.title AS title,
uc_order_products.price AS price,
uc_order_products.qty AS 'quantity',
(uc_order_products.qty * uc_order_products.price) AS 'total'
FROM uc_orders uc_orders
LEFT JOIN uc_order_products uc_order_products ON uc_orders.order_id = uc_order_products.order_id
WHERE uc_orders.order_status IN ('completed')) AS detailed_report
GROUP BY nid
```

The output produced is:

[image]

When I add the date fields to the query then the quantity amount is incorrect. I don't understand why that is. Here is the revised query:

```
SELECT  event_dates.field_dates_value AS start_date,
event_dates.field_dates_value2 AS end_date,
detailed_report.title AS title,
detailed_report.nid AS nid,
detailed_report.price AS 'price',
SUM(detailed_report.quantity) AS 'total_quantity',
SUM(detailed_report.total) AS 'total_revenue' 
FROM (SELECT uc_order_products.nid AS 'nid',
uc_orders.order_id AS 'order_id',
uc_order_products.title AS title,
uc_order_products.price AS price,
uc_order_products.qty AS 'quantity',
(uc_order_products.qty * uc_order_products.price) AS 'total'
FROM uc_orders uc_orders
LEFT JOIN uc_order_products uc_order_products ON uc_orders.order_id = uc_order_products.order_id
WHERE uc_orders.order_status IN ('completed')) AS detailed_report
LEFT JOIN content_field_dates event_dates ON detailed_report.nid =event_dates.nid
GROUP BY nid
```

The result is as follows:

[image: result of query]

Notice that the quantity column values are incorrect. Why is this? Can someone explain what I have done wrong and how to correct it? I am completely baffled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would dissect the sql that you are using into pieces, and determine if there is anything different in the table expression you are using.

Then, if that was ok, i would remove the sum from the select and see if there are any differences with the left join to the new table vs. not having it.